# Text Home on Joomla website

Tags: joomla

There is standing a block within the text "Home" this is above the article "Test" which i add by myself.

Now my question is how can i remove this Home from my website? I have already turned the breadcrumbs off.

Comment: This is my site: http://ajaxworldd.comeze.com/

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your main menu and select the first item, our will be called "home". Look at the parameters on the right hand side, and disable the parameter called Show Page Heading.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now so I am not sure but check this:

```
1. Log in to your Joomla administrator backend.
2. Click on ‘Extensions’,'Module Manager’.
3. Search for ‘Breadcrumbs’ module, edit it.
4. Under the options, set “Show Home” = No
```

Edit:
Probably this is not your problem, @seavers 's answer probably will solve.